# Using ADAL in .net 3.5

Tags: azure, oauth, adal

I have an AzureAD registered Web API working correctly. I am able to acquire the access token by means of AcquireTokenAsync. No problems there. However, no I need to downgrade my rest client library to .net 3.5. I am not being able to use ADAL in .net 3.5. AcquireTokenAsync returns a Task, which is not supported in 3.5. I have read in some tutorials that there is a non async verstion of the method (AcquireToken) [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretoken.aspx). But I just can't access that method. Also, when I try to install that specific version of ADAL(2.19.208020213) I get a Nuget error saying there is no version supported to .Net 3.5

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I am trying to find out which version of ADAL targets .Net 3.5 so I can install it in my project.

**UPDATE 2**

If ADAL is not supported in .Net 3.5, what are my options to obtain authorization token from Azure AD in .net 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

The library only supports 4.5 because async support was added in that .net  release. You may need to dig back to very old versions of the library to get older .net sdk to work. But you would lose significant big fixes and features.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of that. I need to know which version I need to install in .Net 3.5 (if possible). I updated my question.

Comment: Maybe start from early preview release of 2.x