# Got some questions about ADFS, WebAPI and legacy apps

Tags: wpf, winforms, asp.net-web-api2, adfs

We're working on various WPF applications in our enterprise. We are using AD to authenticate users, however our IT department wants us to start using ADFS instead. I have no experience with ADFS. The IT folks are going to write the ADFS service which we'll consume. It is my understanding that ADFS interacts with an endpoint that's a URI. I think it would probably be a good idea to use a WebAPI service and interact with the ADFS service and let all of the WPF apps reference the WebAPI service(s). (Whether there's only 1 or multiple WebAPI's we'll work out later.)

We have a LOT of legacy applications written using .NET 2. If we go the route of writing a WebAPI to authenticate and authorize against a ADFS service, we'll use VS 2015 and .NET 4.6 to write them. In a blog post I've read ([Securing a Web API with ADFS on WS2012 R2 Got Even Easier](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/)) they use of Adal .NET. Is Adal .NET restricted to higher levels of the .NET framework like 3.5 and above? If so, wouldn't it be better to use POCO classes in our WebAPI service that .NET 2 would understand and let the WebAPI service communicate with legacy clients that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ADFS 3.0, you are restricted to the one OAuth use case (Authorisation code grant - private) as above.

There is no OpenID Connect etc. (But you could get that with ADFS 4.0 - Server 2016).

You need .NET 4.5 - [Using ADAL in .net 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38576618/9922).

Even if you added WIF to your legacy apps., that still needs .NET 3.5.